# $wpdb insert big problem, very weird

Tags: insert, wordpress

I use $wpdb to insert some rows with information in a specific table... Everything works fine until I add some img tags without a value (a picture), in the theme, or post.

Eample: `<img src="">`

I think that this refreshes (the browser tries to find the image and opens the html file again..) the page and recalls insert options that duplicates the rows in the table.

In Chrome the row is duplicated 3 times, in Firefox 2 times and in Opera, IE works fine, how to fix it and how to prevent duplicate/multiple inserts?

For inserting I use this code:

```
$data_array = array('aff_id' => $aff_id, 'remote_addr' => $remoteaddress, 'url' => $curentpage, 'referrer' => $httpreferer);
    $wpdb->insert( 'amember_aff_clicks', $data_array );
```

it connects to an external $table but the same database.

Answer (score 0):

escape your values: `$remoteaddress = $wpdb->escape($remoteaddress));`. Better yet use `$wpdb->prepare();`

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369468/first-wpdb-insert-to-mysql-new-table-isnt-working/6369976#6369976) for a quick example and read the [$wpdb class reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)