# First wpdb insert to mySql new table isn't working

Tags: mysql, insert, wordpress

I created a new mySql table and I need the first field to be an index and a key.
I'm not sure I got the terminology right but I simply need that field to automatically increment by 1 with each insert.
So I defined that field as an `index` and gave it the `auto_increment` attribute.
Now I try to insert the first row like this:

```
$wpdb->insert('wp_branches', array(user_id=>$user_id, branchName=>$bname));
```

The index/key field `branchId` is missing from this query because I'm counting on the db to automatically give it the value 1 since it's the first insert, and then increment it with every additional insert.
For some reason the row isn't being inserted and db is left empty.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Found the problem. Wrong field name. `user_id` should be `userId`.

Answer (score 4):

try like so:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare(
     "INSERT INTO `wp_branches` (`user_id`,`branchName`) values (%d,%s)", 
      $user_id, $bname);

$wpdb->query($sql);
```

this will protect you against "injections" too.

Comment: @Ярослав Рахматуллин, I found the problem (wrong field name) but thanks for the suggestion to protect from injections. I'll use it.

Comment: sure. np. try $wpdb->show_errors(); and $wpdb->print_error(); next time ;)

Comment: `$wpdb->insert` filters the query internally, so using prepare does not really add any protection against SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

modified so:

```
$wpdb->insert('wp_branches', array('user_id' => $user_id, 'branchName' => $bname));
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't make a difference.